# TeX Live 2023 Install additional otf, ttf fonts

Tags: fonts, luatex, fontspec, texlive

I have installed TeX Live 2023 completely. I compile with Lualatex. Now the compiler tells me that it still wants the following fonts:

Package fontspec: The font "NotoSansArabic" cannot be found.

Package fontspec: The font "NotoSansDevanagari" cannot be found.

Package fontspec: The font "NotoSansHebrew" cannot be found.

Package fontspec: The font "NotoSansCJKJP" cannot be found.

How do I install the missing fonts? In which directory? etc. There is surely a HowTo install ...

Thanks for the help

Comment: "It still wants"? Surely it is your document that wants it.

Comment: get them from https://fonts.google.com/noto and install them as you would install fonts for other applications. And don't cross post without mentioning where you asked the question too.

Comment: Possibility: Are the Noto fonts part of your operating system, rather than within TeX? LuaLaTeX can find system fonts, in most cases. Exception might be using a Termux subsystem on Android, because Android cannot be seen by TeXlive without special instructions. Otherwise, install the Noto fonts, as Ulrike stated above.